# Jenkins | UNIX | ZIP

Tags: shell, jenkins, unix, zip

```
zip -r social.zip Google/Facebook/Instagram/*
```

I'm using the above command in Jenkins script to create a ZIP. But I don't want the same directiory structure in ZIP. I need all the directories & files under Google/Facebook/Instagram/* directly in ZIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Google/Facebook/Instagram` your current directory by doing a `cd` or `pushd` then return to your original directory.

`(cd Google/Facebook/Instagram ; zip -r ../../../social.zip *)`

or

`pushd Google/Facebook/Instagram ; zip -r ../../../social.zip * ; popd`

Answer (score 1):

[Read the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip); `zip -j -r ...` or `zip --junk-paths -r ...`

It even says:

> You may want to make a zip archive that contains the files in foo, without recording the directory name, foo. You can use the -j option to leave off the paths, as in:
>
> `zip -j foo foo/*`

Comment: this eliminates the subfolders inside foo